# Iterate backwards with fadeOut - Can't figure out condition

Tags: jquery, fadein, fadeout, loops

I got this code here: http://jsfiddle.net/Az5Uk/

```
function fadeIt (element) {

    var elem = $(element).hide();
    var elemLen = $(element).length;

    elem.each(function (i){
        $(this).delay(i * 900).fadeIn(900);

        if (i == elemLen -1) {

            $($(this).get().reverse()).each(function(i) {
                 $(this).delay(elemLen * 900).fadeOut(900);
            });
        }
    });

}

fadeIt(".animate");​
```

What I want to do: Fade in the three Xs on after each other, then fade them out backwards. This should all be part of an recursive function.

I haven't written the recursive part in the example because I can't figure out why the fade out stops after one X. Or in other words: I know that it is because of `if (i == elemLen -1)` but I don't know how to edit the condition to make it fade out all three Xs.

I already have tried `if (i == elemLen -1 || i == elemLen -2)`, but with that syntax it fades out the middle X first, then the last X. So this is not working.

Could anyone please push me into the right direction?

Comment: There is no recursion in this if I see correctly.

Comment: Thats true - I also pointed that out. I have just mentioned it so it's easier to understand what I want to do. My question is ho to set the if condition to make all Xs fade out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/npwvH/

I'm not really good at interpreting someone else's code, so I wrote you an alternative.

```
function ponyo(elements, anim) {
    elements.each(function(i) {
        $(this).delay(i*900)[anim](900);
    });
    setTimeout(function() {
        ponyo($(elements.get().reverse()), (anim=='fadeIn')?'fadeOut':'fadeIn');
    }, elements.length * 900);
}
ponyo($(".animate").hide(), 'fadeIn');​
```

it simply does the animation like you did, waits the amount of time necessary for the animation to complete (setTimeout), and then calls the opposite animation on the reversed collection.